# Implicit conversion from varchr to int

Tags: sql-server

I have been strugglling for a few hours with this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PS_PICSignaturesLire]
    (@NumEm VARCHAR(10) = '', 
     @LibPdtTitre VARCHAR(128) = '', 
     @LibEpiTitre VARCHAR(128) = '', 
     @IdSts INT = -1,
     @IdYpr INT = -1,
     @DtDebut DATETIME = NULL,
     @DtFin DATETIME = NULL,
     @IdPss INT = -1)  
AS  
BEGIN  
    IF (@NumEm != '')  
    BEGIN  
      SET @NumEm = LTRIM(RTRIM(@NumEm))  
    END  

    IF (@LibPdtTitre != '')  
    BEGIN  
        SET @LibPdtTitre = LTRIM(RTRIM(@LibPdtTitre))  
    END  

    IF (@LibEpiTitre != '')  
    BEGIN  
        SET @LibEpiTitre = LTRIM(RTRIM(@LibEpiTitre))  
    END  

    IF @DtDebut IS NULL  
    BEGIN  
        SET @DtDebut = CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/1900', 103)  
    END  

    IF @DtFin IS NULL  
    BEGIN  
        SET @DtFin = DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE())  
    END  

    DECLARE @MinDate DATETIME  
    SET @MinDate =  CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/1900', 103)  

    CREATE TABLE #DatesFB
    (
        IdVfs INT, 
        DtEnvoiFB DATETIME, 
        DtModif DATETIME, 
        DtSignature DATETIME, 
        DtMax DATETIME
    )  

    INSERT INTO  #DatesFB(IdVfs, DtEnvoiFB, DtModif, DtSignature, DtMax)  
        SELECT 
            IdVfs, ISNULL(DtEnvoiFB, '1901-01-01'), ISNULL(DtModif, '1901-01-01'), 
            ISNULL(DtSignature, '1901-01-01'), ISNULL(DtModif, '1901-01-01')  
        FROM 
            VideoFacebookSignature  

    UPDATE #DatesFB  
    SET DtMax = DtEnvoiFB  
    WHERE DtEnvoiFB >= DtMax  

    UPDATE #DatesFB  
    SET DtMax = DtSignature  
    WHERE DtSignature >= DtMax  

    SELECT 
        lst.NumEm, lst.NumVre,  
        lst.IdYpr, lst.LibYpr,  
        CASE lst.IdYis WHEN 1 THEN 'PAD' ELSE 'Live' END AS LibYis,  
        lst.IdPdt, lst.LibPdtTitre,
        lst.IdSai, lst.LibSaiTitre,
        lst.IdEpi, lst.LibEpiTitre,   
        CASE 
           WHEN lst.TcDuree < 0 
              THEN '00:00:00' 
              ELSE dbo.FN_ConvertirTimeHHMMSS(lst.TcDuree) 
        END AS TcDuree,  
        lst.IdSts,  
        sts.LibSts AS LibSts,    
        CASE WHEN lst.DtModif = @MinDate THEN NULL ELSE lst.DtModif END AS DtModif,  
        pss.IdPss,  
        LibPssCourt AS LibPss,
        Statut
    FROM  
        (SELECT 
             NumEM, NumVre, IdEpi, LibEpiTitre,  
             IdPdt, LibPdtTitre, IdSai, LibSaiTitre,
             IdYpr, LibYpr, DiffusionId, IdYis,  
             MAX(IdSts) AS IdSts,      
             MAX(ISNULL(DtModif, @MinDate)) AS DtModif,  
             MAX(TcDuree) As TcDuree,  
             IdPss AS IdPss,
             MAX(Statut) AS Statut
         FROM  
             ( 
                 /* SELECT INA */  
                 SELECT 
                     ivs.NumEM, ivs.Numvre, epi.IdEpi, epi.LibEpiTitre,  
                     pdt.IdPdt, pdt.LibPdtTitre, sai.IdSai, sai.LibSaiTitre,
                     pdt.IdYpr, ypr.LibYpr, ivi.RefIvi As DiffusionId, ivi.idYis,  
                     mis.IdSts AS IdSts,      
                     ISNULL(ivi.DtIviModif, ISNULL(ivi.DtIviEnvoi, ivi.DtIviSignature)) AS DtModif,      
                     ivi.TcIviDuree AS TcDuree,  
                     1 AS IndINA,  
                     0 AS IndGoogle,  
                     1 AS IdPss,
                     mis.IdSts AS Statut 
                 FROM  
                     (SELECT 
                          IdIvs, NumEM, Numvre  
                      FROM INAVersion  
                      WHERE NumEM != ''  
                        AND NumEM LIKE '%' + @NumEm + '%') ivs  
                 INNER JOIN 
                     INAVideo ivi ON ivs.IdIvs = ivi.IdIvs  
                 INNER JOIN  
                     (SELECT 
                          IdEpi, LibEpiTitre, NumEM, IdPdt, IdSai
                      FROM Episode  
                      WHERE NumEM != ''  
                        AND NumEM LIKE '%' + @NumEm + '%'  
                        AND LibEpiTitre LIKE '%' + @LibEpiTitre + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI) epi ON epi.NumEM = ivs.NumEM  
                 INNER JOIN  
                     (SELECT 
                          IdPdt, LibPdtTitre, IdYpr  
                      FROM Produit  
                      WHERE LibPdtTitre LIKE '%' + @LibPdtTitre + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI  
                        AND IdYpr = CASE WHEN @IdYpr = -1 THEN IdYpr ELSE @IdYpr END) pdt ON pdt.IdPdt = epi.IdPdt  
                 INNER JOIN  
                     (SELECT IdSai, LibSaiTitre 
                      FROM Saison) sai ON sai.IdSai = epi.IdSai  

   INNER JOIN PICMappingINAStatutSignature mis ON mis.IdSis = ivi.IdSis  
   INNER JOIN  
   (  
    SELECT IdYpr,  
      LibYpr  
    FROM TypeProgramme  
    WHERE IdYpr = CASE WHEN @IdYpr = -1 THEN IdYpr ELSE @IdYpr END  
   ) ypr ON ypr.IdYpr = pdt.IdYpr  
   WHERE @IdPss IN (-1, 1)  

   UNION ALL  

   /* SELECT GOOGLE */  
   SELECT pgs.NumEM,  
    pgs.NumVre,  
    epi.IdEpi,  
    epi.LibEpiTitre,  
    pdt.IdPdt,  
    pdt.LibPdtTitre,
    sai.IdSai,
    sai.LibSaiTitre,
    pdt.IdYpr,  
    ypr.LibYpr,  
    vgs.DiffusionID,  
    CASE WHEN vgs.IndVgsLive = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IdYis, -- PAD      
    mgs.IdSts AS IdSts,      
    vgs.DtModification AS DtModif,  
    vgs.TcVgsDuree AS TcDuree,  
    0 AS IndINA,  
    1 AS IndGoogle,  
    2 AS IdPss,
    mgs.IdSts AS Statut   
   FROM  
   (  
    SELECT IdPgs,  
      IdSpg,  
      NumEM,  
      NumVre  
    FROM ProgrammeGoogleSignature  
    WHERE NumEM != ''  
     AND NumEM LIKE '%' + @NumEm + '%'  
   ) pgs  
   INNER JOIN VideoGoogleSignature vgs ON vgs.IdPgs = pgs.IdPgs  
   INNER JOIN  
   (  
    SELECT IdEpi,  
      LibEpiTitre,  
      NumEM,  
      IdPdt,
      IdSai
    FROM Episode  
    WHERE NumEM != ''  
     AND NumEM LIKE '%' + @NumEm + '%'  
     AND LibEpiTitre LIKE '%' + @LibEpiTitre + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI  
   ) epi ON epi.NumEM = pgs.NumEM  
   INNER JOIN  
   (  
    SELECT IdPdt,  
      LibPdtTitre,  
      IdYpr  
    FROM Produit  
    WHERE LibPdtTitre LIKE '%' + @LibPdtTitre + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI  
     AND IdYpr = CASE WHEN @IdYpr = -1 THEN IdYpr ELSE @IdYpr END  
   ) pdt ON pdt.IdPdt = epi.IdPdt 

   INNER JOIN  
   (  
    SELECT IdSai,  
    LibSaiTitre 
    FROM Saison  
   ) sai ON sai.IdSai = epi.IdSai
   INNER JOIN PICMappingStatutGoogleSignature mgs ON mgs.IdSpg = CASE WHEN IndVgsLive = 1 THEN pgs.IdSpg ELSE vgs.IdSvg END  
   INNER JOIN  
   (  
    SELECT IdYpr,  
      LibYpr  
    FROM TypeProgramme  
    WHERE IdYpr = CASE WHEN @IdYpr = -1 THEN IdYpr ELSE @IdYpr END  
   ) ypr ON ypr.IdYpr = pdt.IdYpr  
   WHERE @IdPss IN (-1, 2)  

   UNION ALL  

   /* SELECT FACEBOOK */  
   SELECT pfs.NumEM,  
    convert(varchar(8), pfs.NumVre),  
    epi.IdEpi,  
    epi.LibEpiTitre,  
    pdt.IdPdt,  
    pdt.LibPdtTitre,  
    pdt.IdYpr, 
    sai.IdSai,
    sai.LibSaiTitre,
    ypr.LibYpr,  
    vfs.NumEA as DiffusionID,  
    1 AS IdYis, -- PAD      
    mgs.IdSts AS IdSts,      
    dt.DtMax AS DtModif, --Date max  
    spm.TcSpmDuree AS TcDuree,  
    0 AS IndINA,  
    0 AS IndGoogle,  
    3 AS IdPss,
    mgs.IdSsf AS Statut    
   FROM  
   (  
    SELECT IdPfs,  
      NumEM,  
      NumVre  
    FROM ProgrammeFacebookSignature  
    WHERE NumEM != ''  
     AND NumEM LIKE '%' + @NumEm + '%'  
     AND IdSnf = 1
   ) pfs  
   INNER JOIN VideoFacebookSignature vfs ON vfs.IdPfs = pfs.IdPfs  
   INNER JOIN #DatesFB dt on vfs.IdVfs = dt.IdVfs  
   INNER JOIN  
   (  
    SELECT IdEpi,  
      LibEpiTitre,  
      NumEM,  
      IdPdt,
      IdSai
    FROM Episode  
    WHERE NumEM != ''  
     AND NumEM LIKE '%' + @NumEm + '%'  
     AND LibEpiTitre LIKE '%' + @LibEpiTitre + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI  
   ) epi ON epi.NumEM = pfs.NumEM  
   INNER JOIN  
   (  
    SELECT IdPdt,  
      LibPdtTitre,  
      IdYpr  
    FROM Produit  
    WHERE LibPdtTitre LIKE '%' + @LibPdtTitre + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI  
     AND IdYpr = CASE WHEN @IdYpr = -1 THEN IdYpr ELSE @IdYpr END  
   ) pdt ON pdt.IdPdt = epi.IdPdt  

   INNER JOIN  
   (  
    SELECT IdSai,  
      LibSaiTitre 
    FROM Saison  
   ) sai ON sai.IdSai = epi.IdSai  


   INNER JOIN PICMappingStatutFacebookSignature mgs ON mgs.IdSsf = vfs.IdSsf  
   INNER JOIN SupportMedia spm on vfs.NumEA = spm.RefSpmNumero  
   INNER JOIN  
   (  
    SELECT IdYpr,  
      LibYpr  
    FROM TypeProgramme  
    WHERE IdYpr = CASE WHEN @IdYpr = -1 THEN IdYpr ELSE @IdYpr END  
   ) ypr ON ypr.IdYpr = pdt.IdYpr  
   WHERE @IdPss IN (-1, 3)  

  ) tmp  
  GROUP BY NumEM, NumVre, IdEpi, LibEpiTitre, IdPdt, LibPdtTitre, IdSai, LibSaiTitre, IdYpr, LibYpr, DiffusionID, idYis, IdPss, Statut 
 ) lst  
 LEFT JOIN PICStatutSignature sts ON sts.IdSts = lst.IdSts   
 INNER JOIN PICSystemeSignature pss ON pss.IdPss = lst.IdPss   
 WHERE @IdSts IN (-1, lst.IdSts)  
 AND CASE WHEN DtModif = @MinDate THEN DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE()) ELSE DtModif END <= DATEADD(day,1,@DtFin) AND DtModif >= @DtDebut  
 AND (DtModif >= @DtDebut OR DtModif <= DATEADD(day,1,@DtFin))  
 ORDER BY lst.NumEM, lst.NumVre  
 DROP TABLE #DatesFB  
END
```

I have the followin error when executing it

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PS_PICSignaturesLire, Line 48 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '22 initiale' to data type int

'22 initiale' is a not null VARCHAR (128)

I don't even understand why SQL Server is trying to convert it to an int. I think that it does so when applying the GROUP BY statement.

Comment: *"I think that it does so when applying the GROUP BY statement."* It's definitely not the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: What exactly is line 48 anyway?

Comment: Some formatting would be a HUGE help. Don't be scared to use white to separate your code. And the {tab} key is helpful do indent things. But seriously you can't just drop 300+ line of sql and expect somebody to be able to tell you where the problem is. My guess is you are joining somewhere in here and one side is an int and the other is a varchar.

Comment: '22 initiale' is stored in which column and table?
What is the value of the stored procedure input parameters?

Comment: '22 initial' is stored in "Saison" table in "LibSaiTitre" column. All inputs are NULL, they are used to filter results.